# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]) on amazon EC2 production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I have deployed my application on amazon ec2 instance with nginx and passenger and its working proper while I am calling `api.subdomain.domain.com/admin` and its work perfectly as I want to run.

But While I am calling url `api.subdomain.domain.com/v1/products` then I am getting below errors. Its properly working on local with development as well production mode. Only API call is not working.

I have used `ruby 2.2.2` and `rails 4.2.3`.

Let me know if anyone wants more details regarding the issue.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/v1/products"):
App 7773 stdout:   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
App 7773 stdout:   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
App 7773 stdout:   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
App 7773 stdout:   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
App 7773 stdout:   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
App 7773 stdout:   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
App 7773 stdout:   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
App 7773 stdout:   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 7773 stdout:   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
App 7773 stdout:   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
App 7773 stdout:   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
App 7773 stdout:
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
    namespace :api, path: nil, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
      namespace :v1 do
        get "/products" => "products#all_details"
      end

      namespace :v2 do
        get "/products" => "products#all_details"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I do rake routes then I got this routes

```
api_v1_products GET        /v1/products(.:format)                    api/v1/products#all_details {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>"json"}
```

Comment: Post your config/routes.rb from amazon server

Comment: @RAJ I have added on question. Same code also working on another amazon ec2 server. So I think its not a coding issue. But even let me know your thoughts. So I will search regarding that.

Comment: As it is generate `/api/v1/products`

Please try `shallow`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495197/shallow-routes-inside-a-namespace-with-path-param-not-working

Comment: @RajarshiDas I have tried this but its not working :(

Comment: @SachinGevariya, Can you try to run `rake routes` on server in production mode and see if it still shows the requried path?

Comment: @RAJ I do have updated my questions for the same. BTW it showing there

Comment: ahhh i think /etc/hosts did you modify it

Comment: No. I have not modified it

Comment: Did you try `api.subdomain.domain.com/v1/products.json` ? 
because you are adding json format in route configuration block.

Comment: No its correct. That's not an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find out a solution for that. Here issue is for subdomains. Here I do have 2 subdomains and rails by default set 1 as TLD([Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)). I have increased it with 2 and its working for me.

Here for set 2 as value I have added below configuration on `production.rb`

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

Note: Actually TLD is not used for pre subdomain but its worked for me so I have given solution over here. Its used for .com, .co.in..